# swagger-ui not working in docker container

Tags: spring-boot, jax-rs, cxf, swagger, swagger-ui

swagger-ui does not render when Spring Boot application is running in a docker container, only swagger.json. It works fine when running locally (IntelliJ). I'm not clear on how boot adds static resources to the fatjar. I tries several variations of what is shown [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) but no luck.

I am using apache cxf with spring boot as shown [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/swagger2feature.html)

Relevant sections...

```
//build.gradle
compile('org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger:3.1.7')
compile('org.webjars:swagger-ui:2.2.6')
//application.yml
cxf:
  jaxrs:
  component-scan: true
  component-scan-packages: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.swagger
```

Comment: i managed to get swagger-ui working in a docker container, can you post your configuration ?